# Tkinter in Python 3.4 on Windows don't post internal clipboard data to the Windows clipboard on exit

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, clipboard, python-3.4

I use the following code to place result of my small scripts in clipboard.

```
from tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append("Result")
```

It works fine on Python version 3.3.5 and earlier. But when I upgrade to Python 3.4 it was receive empty clipboard. I tried the 3.4.0, 3.4.1 and 3.4.2 and all received one result (empty clipboard). If I prevent the script from the immediate exit, adding `input()` after `clipboard_append()`, I see that clipboard contains the correct "Result".

**Update1:**

The modified test script shows that the problem is not a timing issue:

```
from tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append("Result")
input()
r.destroy()
```

If I run this script, wait a few seconds, press Enter, I receive empty clipboard.

If I run script, switch to any other window and press Ctrl+V, I receive "Result" and "Result" remains in clipboard after script exits.

I think in tcl/tk 8.6 `clipboard_clear()` affect system clipboard, but `clipboard_append` affect only internal tcl/tk clipboard that transfered to system clipboard only by OS request. Looks like it was done in Linux, that don't have system clipboard.

**Update2:**

Last mention clipboard in [Tk changelog](http://upstream-tracker.org/changelogs/tk/8.6.1/changelog.html) refers to the 2004:

```
2004-05-03 (bug fix)[939389, 822002, 732662] Correctly post internal 
clipboard data to the Windows clipboard on exit. (hobbs)
```

It seems that the error corrected in 2004 returned to us 10 years later.

Comment: I have the same problem, I hope you posted a bug report... (bugs.python.org)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that 'Result' never gets to the clipboard, rather than being cleared. 3.4 on Windows come with tcl/tk 8.6 instead of 8.5.  I suspect that this is the difference, and it is possibly a timing issue. Does `r.destroy` after the append work?  Explicitly destroying the tk root before exiting python is generally a good idea.  We had problems with the test suite until we started doing this.

Comment: The modified test script shows that the problem is not a timing issue:

Comment: I tried to write too much and could not comment. I updated my question by adding new results and ideas.

Comment: I just tried your original 5 lines with 3.4.2 on Win7 and it works.  I have no other ideas why not for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add some delay is useful in my PC(win10, python3.7):

```
from tkinter import Tk
import time


r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append('some string')

r.update()
time.sleep(.2)
r.update()

r.destroy()
```