# tkinter "scrolledtext" copy paste doesn't work reliably

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, copy-paste, tkinter-scrolledtext

I have found a behaviour which seems to be a bug in `tkinter`.
If you run the following (minimal to reproduce the bug) code:

```
import tkinter, tkinter.simpledialog, tkinter.scrolledtext
root = tkinter.Tk('test')
text = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(master=root, wrap='none')
text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)
text.insert(tkinter.END, 'abc\ndef\nghi\nijk')
root.mainloop()
```

then:

- select one row in the `scrolledtext` widget, e.g. the row "ghi",
- copy it with <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>
- do nothing else and close the app

Then paste it (<kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>) in any other Windows app: it won't work, nothing will be pasted. Why?

How to solve this?

---

Note: the expected behaviour is that text copied with CTRL+C should persist in the clipboard even if the app is closed. This is the default behaviour in many Windows software. Example here with `notepad.exe`:
link to the animated screen capture: https://i.imgur.com/li7UvYw.mp4

[image]

Note: this is linked to

- https://bugs.python.org/issue23760
- [Tkinter in Python 3.4 on Windows don't post internal clipboard data to the Windows clipboard on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321333/tkinter-in-python-3-4-on-windows-dont-post-internal-clipboard-data-to-the-windo)
- [Tk only copies to clipboard if "paste" is used before program exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178950/tk-only-copies-to-clipboard-if-paste-is-used-before-program-exits/46180493#46180493)
- https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview/1844034fffffffffffff
- etc.

Comment: If you kill the `tkinter` window, all of the clipboard items that `tkinter` added get deleted on my computer. Also what is the point of `text.focus()`? Did you mean `text.focus_set()`?

Comment: @TheLizzard I remove the `.focus()` part which was useless for this minimal example.
More important: as an example, even if `notepad.exe` is closed, any copied text will be kept even if notepad.exe is closed. Example: https://imgur.com/li7UvYw This is the expected behaviour. Here with tkinter, it does not work. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: See the edit at the end of the question for an example @TheLizzard.

Comment: @Basj That is just how `tkinter` works. I know it's very annoying and don't know why it is that way. You can instead bind to `Control-c` and use the [`clipboard`](https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/) library to copy the data. That should actually copy the data to the clipboard even if the `tkinter` window is closed.

Comment: @TheLizzard I think this is a bug, as it breaks the expected behaviour and usual convention for all other apps (see notepad.exe as an example).

Comment: @Basj Well IDLE has/had the same [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue40452). Also [sometimes](https://birdeatsbug.com/5-bugs-that-became-features) bugs become features.

Comment: This issue seems OS-specific, I cannot reproduce this behavior on my computer (Linux with tk 8.6.11 and ClipIt clipboard manager) neither with the provided example nor with IDLE.

Comment: @j_4321 The issue that I linked also stated that it doesn't happen on all OSs due to the fact that tcl calls different functions for `TkClipCleanup` depending on the OS. Look at [this](https://bugs.python.org/msg369338)

Comment: @Basj Do you just need a solution that will work on windows or do ou want it to be platform independent? If only on windows, try: `os.system("echo.%s|clip" % "The text to copy")`. Taken from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111405)

Comment: I had to deal with this before. I posted an answer a while back related this issue. Let me know if it helps. [tk-only-copies-to-clipboard-if-paste-is-used-before-program-exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178950/tk-only-copies-to-clipboard-if-paste-is-used-before-program-exits/46180493#46180493)

Comment: @Mike-SMT Thanks for the info! Have you tried the solution from https://bugs.python.org/issue23760? i.e. `r.after(100, r.destroy); 
r.mainloop()` to let Tkinter execute the code to copy to system clipboard on exit? I haven't tried yet, but it could be a workaround? Did it work for you?

Comment: You could do something like that but I have not tried. The only reason I ran into the problem originally was when I had copied something as a one off and tried to paste sometime after closing the app. I did not really need to consitantly paste when the app closes so I just went as far as to find a solution for my one off.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`pyperclip`](http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/) which supports Windows, Linux and Mac

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyperclip

def copy(event:tk.Event=None) -> str:
    try:
        text = text_widget.selection_get()
        pyperclip.copy(text)
    except tk.TclError:
        pass
    return "break"

root = tk.Tk()

text_widget = tk.Text(root)
text_widget.pack()
text_widget.bind("<Control-c>", copy)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you `return "break"` from the `copy` function? Also this will raise an error if the user hasn't selected anything. Also something interesting: `pyperclip` creates a new window on windows when you try coping.

Comment: Also is the `pyperclip.paste()` needed? Doesn't it just return whatever is in the clipboard. From reading the library's source code I can see that it basically calls `ctypes.windll.user32.GetClipboardData` and converts it into a string. Otherwise nice answer

Comment: @TheLizzard your last comment is useful: can we provide an answer for this question without using a third party dependance `pyperclip` nor your `echo ... | clip` solution, but just `ctypes` and this winAPI call?

Comment: @Basj Right now the Windows on my machine is very unstable so I can't test anything. I recommend looking at [this](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/blob/781603ea491eefce3b58f4f203bf748dbf9ff003/src/pyperclip/__init__.py#L365). It has all of the code that you could need to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows only solution try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import os

def copy(event:tk.Event=None) -> str:
    try:
        # Get the selected text
        # Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073612/11106801
        text = text_widget.selection_get()
        # Copy the text
        # Inspired from: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111405
        os.system("echo.%s|clip" % text)
        print(f"{text!r} is in the clipboard")
    # No selection was made:
    except tk.TclError:
        pass
    # Stop tkinter's built in copy:
    return "break"

root = tk.Tk()

text_widget = tk.Text(root)
text_widget.pack()
text_widget.bind("<Control-c>", copy)

root.mainloop()
```

Basically I call my own `copy` function whenever the user presses `Control-C`. In that function I use the `clip.exe` program that is part of the OS to copy the text.

Note: my approach to copying data to the clipboard using `os.system`, isn't great as you can't copy `|` characters. I recommend looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard) for better ways. You just need to replace that 1 line of code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you know how is CTRL+C originally implemented in tkinter `scrolledtext`? I had a quick look in the source, but I didn't find it. Maybe a tweak there (that could be proposed as PR in Python core repo?) could work? Until this is solved, your solution is helpful indeed!

Comment: I looked in the source @TheLizzard,  `scrolledtext` is a child class of `Text` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L3561  but I found nothing about the handling of copy/paste there.

Comment: @Basj That is done in `tcl`. Basically `tcl` is a programming language to create GUIs. There is a module `_tkinter` which converts a lot of the `tcl` features into python (it's the C part of `tkinter`). Then there is `tkinter` which uses `_tkinter`. By returning `"break"` from my function, I tell `tcl` to not call the usual `Control-C` binding.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pyperclip` and `root.bind_all()` we can solve the problem.

```
import tkinter, tkinter.simpledialog, tkinter.scrolledtext 
import pyperclip as clip

root = tkinter.Tk('test')

text = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(master=root, wrap='none')
def _copy(event):
   try:
      string = text.selection_get()
      clip.copy(string)
   except:pass

root.bind_all("<Control-c>",_copy)

text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)
text.insert(tkinter.END,'abc\ndef\nghi\njkl')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using `bind_all`? I think that `bind_all` should be discouraged. Also this is the same as @Chandan's answer. The only difference is that you used `.bind_all` and a scrolled text (which wasn't in the question but ok).

Comment: Also you import `simpledialog` without using it. Also why are you passing in `"test"` when creating `tkinter.Tk`? If you want to set the titlebar title for the window, use `root.title(....)`.

Comment: My bad about the scrolled text not being needed but my other points still stand.

Comment: Using bind on scrolledtext wont work and it shoul be bind_all on master
And about import and title, i didnt change the question those were part of question. I just added the Function and bind_all and the rest were with the question.